# Email id entry into cpanel mailing list

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, form-submit, elementor, mailing-list

I have a wordpress website and have set up a subscribe form by using Elementor Form. I want to add the email address entry to the mailing list that i have created in cpanel.

How to make this happen?